Why is termios in glibc and the kernel?
Question was closed. Allegedly it is opinion based and questions design decisions though in fact it asks for reasoning and addresses considerations for using one or the other which violates Stackoverflow's question policies. They want the questions once a developer has made the wrong choice and runs into an issue whereby they can answer with something like "you need to the kernel termios api not the C library's". In short they don't want to inform.

Stack Overflow is exclusively focused on solving practical problems. If the only reason you're asking "why" is curiosity, you don't have a practical problem. (To put it a little differently , is second-guessing decisions made a long time ago going to change how you go about the practice of writing software today?)

Lot of "curious" people https://lwn.net/Articles/417647/ Maybe you should post your comment there.

Looks like it's a trend https://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=23799

I don't see what any of those links have to do with compliance with Stack Overflow topicality rules.

Some relevant examples: Are language specs and their development history on topic?, What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design? -- granted, this isn't language design, but the same rationale applies.

Read the answer. You might be surprised at just how much they do.

@Charles Duffy Turns out termios is implemented in some kernels. In case you were ever wondering. But don't let that stop you or anyone else at SO from simply closing questions instead of answering them. Which is understable seeing your reps seem to be  built on answers in the docs noone reads instead of actual practical knowledge and experience.

Question was closed. Allegedly it is opinion based and questions design decisions though in fact it asks for reasoning and addresses considerations for using one or the other which violates Stackoverflow's question policies. They want the questions once a developer has made the wrong choice and runs into an issue whereby they can answer with something like "you need to the kernel termios api not the C library's". In short they don't want to inform.

Turns out this is wrong. There are in fact termios implementations in kernels.
